# I can't play on Minecraft PC servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Everything seems to work, but when I try to join a server I get an error[image: The picture proves that everything seems normal] When I try to join either one on the zombiemold servers I get this:[image: The error I'm experiencing]

I don't know what to do.

Comment: The server is too old; your version is more up to date than theirs is.

Comment: This error means you have the wrong version of Minecraft- you may need to either upgrade or downgrade depending on the server.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick replies. how do I figure out what version their server is??

Comment: Provided I found the [right site](http://minecraftservers.org/server/10005#info) for them, it looks like you need version 1.7.9.

Answer (score 4):

This message means that you are using the wrong version of minecraft. "Outdated server" means that the server is using an older version of Minecraft than you are.

The best way to find out what version they're using is to contact the server administrators, or go to their website if they have one.

For the server on the top, it shows the version of spigot you need in red, and sometimes the launcher will also show the version of Minecraft that you need in that manner.